# How to calculate ts1 - ts2.interpolate(index=ts1.index)

Tags: python, pandas

Example data:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from random import randint

base_index = [datetime(2012, 12, 31, 23, 55 + x) for x in range(5)]
index1 = [x + timedelta(seconds=randint(0, 10)) for x in base_index]
index2 = [x + timedelta(seconds=randint(0, 10)) for x in base_index]

ts1 = pd.Series(range(5), index=index1)
ts2 = pd.Series(range(5), index=index2)
```

This results in these time series:

```
2012-12-31 23:55:03    0
2012-12-31 23:56:07    1
2012-12-31 23:57:01    2
2012-12-31 23:58:01    3
2012-12-31 23:59:03    4

2012-12-31 23:55:03    0
2012-12-31 23:56:09    1
2012-12-31 23:57:09    2
2012-12-31 23:58:04    3
2012-12-31 23:59:01    4
```

Now I wish to sample ts2 at the points of ts1's index and subtract those values from ts1. The result should be a timeseries with floats very close to zero. The closest I've come is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ts1": ts1, "ts2": ts2})
df["ts3"] = df["ts2"].interpolate(method="time")
df["ts4"] = df["ts1"] - df["ts3"]
result = df["ts4"].dropna()
```

It gives the result I want:

```
2012-12-31 23:55:03    0.000000
2012-12-31 23:56:07    0.030303
2012-12-31 23:57:01    0.133333
2012-12-31 23:58:01    0.054545
2012-12-31 23:59:03    0.000000
```

But it's not very pretty. Is there a better way?

Comment: This is more of a question for code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ they look at functioning code and recommend improvements

Comment: Cyber: I beg to differ. This is a very generic problem and StackOverflow would benefit from having an answer. I've searched for close to an hour and haven't found an answer.

Comment: Cyber: besides, you're basically complaining that I've taken the time and effort to find a way around my problem instead of just posting the problem outright and ask for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your soln is resonable. Putting both timeseries in the Frame automatically aligns them.

This is another way

Align the series (essentially combine their index)

```
In [30]: ats1,ats2 = ts1.align(ts2)
```

The interpolated output of the aligned series

```
In [32]: ats2.interpolate(method='time')
Out[32]: 
2012-12-31 23:55:00    0.000000
2012-12-31 23:56:09    0.985714
2012-12-31 23:56:10    1.000000
2012-12-31 23:57:00    1.980392
2012-12-31 23:57:01    2.000000
2012-12-31 23:58:00    3.000000
2012-12-31 23:58:07    3.100000
2012-12-31 23:59:04    3.914286
2012-12-31 23:59:10    4.000000
dtype: float64
```

Show me only values in the original ts1

```
In [33]: ats2.interpolate(method='time').reindex_like(ts1)
Out[33]: 
2012-12-31 23:55:00    0.000000
2012-12-31 23:56:09    0.985714
2012-12-31 23:57:00    1.980392
2012-12-31 23:58:07    3.100000
2012-12-31 23:59:04    3.914286
dtype: float64

In [34]: ts1
Out[34]: 
2012-12-31 23:55:00    0
2012-12-31 23:56:09    1
2012-12-31 23:57:00    2
2012-12-31 23:58:07    3
2012-12-31 23:59:04    4
dtype: int64

In [35]:
```

Interpolate and eliminate the original values and show me the differential

```
In [31]: ts1-ats2.interpolate(method='time').reindex_like(ts1)
Out[31]: 
2012-12-31 23:55:00    0.000000
2012-12-31 23:56:09    0.014286
2012-12-31 23:57:00    0.019608
2012-12-31 23:58:07   -0.100000
2012-12-31 23:59:04    0.085714
dtype: float64
```